# How to use mod_rewrite in .htaccess to point to folder outside WordPress installation

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

## Problem

I would like to edit the WordPress .htaccess file such that requests to www.mydomain.com/nonwordpress are rewritten to point to a folder outside the WordPress installation.

## Details

In Detail: The WordPress installation is on shared hosting and the domain is configured to point to the WordPress installation:

**www.mydomain.com** -> /absolute_path_on_server/htdocs/**wordpress**

Now I would like to have a different directory "nonwordpress" outside the "wordpress" folder to be redirected like this:

**www.mydomain.com/nonwordpress/** -> /absolute_path_on_server/htdocs/**nonwordpress**

Note that the other folder is outside the root folder to which the domain points.

## What I tried:

I tried modifying the .htaccess file in the folder "wordpress" by adding the following line for rewriting requests to mydomain.com/nonwordpress:

```
RewriteRule ^/nonwordpress/(.*)$   /absolute_path_on_server/htdocs/nonwordpress/$1
```

The entire .htaccess file now looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/nonwordpress/(.*)$   /absolute_path_on_server/htdocs/nonwordpress/$1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Unfortunately it has no effect, so when I go to mydomain.com/nonwordpress I get a 404 site not found error (from WordPress) instead of the folder contents.

I also tried to achieve the rewriting by replacing the absolute path by a relative path:

```
RewriteRule ^/nonwordpress/(.*)$   ../nonwordpress/$1
```

Again, the same error.

Any idea how to do this, if it can be done at all, will be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers need good questions. Have a look at how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can edit your questions to make it easier to get help.  Please don't include images, include the data in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have tried to follow the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Why this doesn't work the way you expect, see [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> The *Substitution* of a rewrite rule is the string that replaces the original URL-path that was matched by Pattern. The Substitution may be a:
>
> **file-system path**
> Designates the location on the file-system of the resource to be delivered to the client. *Substitutions are only treated as a file-system path when the rule is configured in server (virtualhost) context* and the first component of the path in the substitution exists in the file-system
> **URL-path**
> ...

So this cannot work, when you put it in a .htaccess file. To have the desired effect, you need to put it in the main configuration wrapped inside a [`VirtualHost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) directive.

Although in your case, it would be easier to utilize an [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)

```
Alias /nonwordpress/ /absolute_path_on_server/htdocs/nonwordpress/
```

but again, this is also only allowed in

> Context:   server config, virtual host, directory

Comment: Okay, so this cannot be done on a shared server if I understand correctly. Too bad. Thanks for your help!